# A metric capped at a maximum value is a metric

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose $d$ is a metric on the set $X$ and $R$ is a real number with $R>0$. For $x$, $y \in X$ define the function $d_R$ by:
$$ 
d_R(x,y) = \begin{cases}
d(x,y) & \text{if } d(x,y) \leq R \\
R & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$
Essentially we have "capped" the metric $d$ at the value $R$.

Show that $d_R$ is a metric on $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be a metric, $d_R$ must satisfy the following three conditions:

1. $d_R(x,y) \geq 0$ for all $x$, $y \in X$.
2. $d_R(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $x=y$.
3. $d_R(x,y) = d_R(y,x)$ for all $x$, $y\in X$.
4. $d_R(x,z) \leq d_R(x,y) + d_R(y,z)$ for all $x$, $y$, $z \in X$ (the triangle inequality)

Take these conditions in turn. Beforehand, note that for any $x$, $y \in X$ we have $d_R(x,y) \leq d(x,y)$ and $d_R(x,y) \leq R$.

1. $d_R(x,y)$ is either equal to $d(x,y) \geq 0$ or equal to $R \geq 0$ so $d_R(x,y) \geq 0$.
2. If $x = y$ then $d(x,y) = 0 <R$. Hence $d_R(x,y) = d(x,y) = 0$.
   If $d_R(x,y) = 0$ then $d(x,y)$ cannot be more than $R$ or $d_R(x,y)$ would have been $R$. Thus $d(x,y) = d_R(x,y) = 0$ so $x=y$.
3. Note that $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ for all $x, y \in X$ and so the formula for $d_R(x,y)$ is symmetric in $x$ and $y$. Hence $d_R(x,y) = d_R(y,x)$.
4. Given $x, y, z \in X$, consider $d_R(x,y) + d_R(y,z)$:
   If $d_R(x,y) = R$ then $d_R(x,y) + d_R(y,z) = R + d_R(y,z) \geq R \geq d_R(x,z)$.
   Similarly if $d_R(y,z) = R$ then $d_R(x,y) + d_R(y,z) \geq d_R(x,z)$.
   If both $d_R(x,y) < R$ and $d_R(y,z)<R$ then this is only possible if $d_R(x,y) = d(x,y)$ and $d_R(y,z) = d(y,z)$. Hence $d_R(x,y) + d_R(x,z) = d(x,y) + d(x,z) \geq d(x,z) \geq d_R(x,z)$.

Therefore $d_R$ is a metric on $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is obvious except the triangle inequality. Notice that, writing it more simply, $d_R(x,y) = \min\{d(x,y), R\}$. You want to prove that: $$d_R(x,y) \leq \min\{d(x,z), R\} + \min\{d(y,z), R\}.$$

Brute force works amazingly well here. Take two cases: $d(x,y) < R$, and $d(x,y) \geq R$. It is not hard as it seems to prove that the left hand side above is less or equal to every possibility of the right side, in both cases. That is, show that $d_R(x,y)$ is less or equal than:

$$\begin{align} & R + R, \\ & d(x,z) + R, \\ & R + d(y,z)\\ \text{and} \quad & d(x,z) + d(y,z).\end{align}$$

Then you win the game.