# Union of metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is the union of two metric spaces a metric space?

I tried it but could't define a suitable metric on intersection. Can somebody help me to understand it?

Comment: Can you make an example? I think you are missing context/hypothesis.

Comment: X and Y both are metric space with some metric d1 and d2. Now, my question is, can union X and Y metric space if yes then give me a metric on union. If no the give an example.

Comment: There is a notion of "disojoint union" of metric spaces, where you consider a metric on $X\coprod Y:=(X\times \{0\})\cup(Y\times\{1\})$.

Comment: I am talking about in general. Let us say ther are not disjoint. For disjoint sets, ofcourse union is metric space.

Comment: Do you want the metric on the union to be somehow compatible with the metrics on the original spaces?  If so, how exactly?  As stated the question doesn't really make any sense--the union isn't literally a metric space; you can only ask whether it can be given the structure of a metric space in a useful way.

Comment: Let $X=[0,3]$ with discrete metric and $Y=[1,4]$ with usual metric. Now, is $\{ 2 \}$ an open set in the proposed union?

Answer (score 7):

Daniel Wainfleet's definition of $d_3$ needs the assumption that $2$ is an upper bound of $d_1$ and $d_2$, otherwise the function $d_3$ will not be a metric (except for the case when some of the sets $X_1$ and $X_2$ is empty). Indeed, suppose for instance that $d_1(x_1,x_1')>2$ for some $x_1,x_1'\in X_1$, and take some $x_2\in X_2$. Then $d_3(x_1,x_1')>d_3(x_1,x_2)+d_3(x_2,x_1')$.

The assumptions $X_1\cap X_2=\varnothing$, $X_1\ne\varnothing$, $X_2\ne\varnothing$ on the metric spaces $(X_1,d_1)$ and $(X_2,d_2)$ are sufficient for proceeding in the following way. We take some $a_1$ in $X_1$ and some $a_2$ in $X_2$, and we define $d:(X_1\cup X_2)^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by setting
$$d(x_1,x_2)=d(x_2,x_1)=\max(d_1(x_1,a_1),d_2(x_2,a_2),1)$$
when $x_1\in X_1$, $x_2\in X_2$, and $d(x,y)=d_i(x,y)$ when $x,y\in X_i$ ($i=1,2$). Then $d$ is always a metric. To show that $d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ for all $x,y,z\in X_1\cup X_2$, we consider separately two cases:
(i) $x$ and $y$ belong to one and same of the sets $X_1$ and $X_2$;
(ii) $x\in X_1$, $y\in X_2$ or $x\in X_2$, $y\in X_1$.
Suppose we have the case (i), and let for instance $x,y\in X_1$. The case $z\in X_1$ is trivial, therefore suppose $z\in X_2$. We have then to show that
$$d_1(x,y)\le\max(d_1(x,a_1),d_2(z,a_2),1)+\max(d_1(y,a_1),d_2(z,a_2),1).$$
and, of course, this inequality follows from the fact that
$$d_1(x,y)\le d_1(x,a_1)+d_1(y,a_1).$$
Suppose now we have the case (ii), and let for instance $x\in X_1$, $y\in X_2$, $z\in X_2$. We have then to show that
$$\max(d_1(x,a_1),d_2(y,a_2),1)\le\max(d_1(x,a_1),d_2(z,a_2),1)+d_2(z,y).$$
Clearly this inequality follows from the inequality
$$d_2(y,a_2)\le d_2(z,a_2)+d_2(z,y)$$
because $d_1(x,a_1)$ and $1$ obviously do not exceed the right-hand side.

Comment: Of course symmetry is present. For elements of one and the same of the spaces it follows from the symmetry of the corresponding metric, otherwise it is directly stated in the definition.

Comment: Excellent. Your metric can be explained by the following construction:
Fix $x_0\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$. Consider $X\sqcup Y\subseteq \{0,1\}\times X\times Y$ via the embedding $x\mapsto (0,x,y_0)$, $y\mapsto (1,x_0,y)$. The product of three metric spaces has the 'max' metric. The induced metric from the embedding is exactly the metric that you defined explicitly.

Comment: Thanks to @Janson for the clever observation!

Comment: @DanielWainfleet’s answer can also be fixed by first capping the two metrics at 1 as per this process: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1020849/160775

Answer (score 2):

(1). If $(X_1,d_1), (X_2,d_2)$ are metric spaces and $X_1\cap X_2=\emptyset$ we can define a metric $d_3$ on $X_1\cup X_2$ by $d_3(x_1,x_2)=1$ when $x_1\in X_1 ,x_2\in X_2,$ and $d_3(x,y)=d_1(x,y)$ when $x,y\in X_1,$ and $d_3(x,y)=d_2(x,y)$ when $x,y\in X_2.$ Then the subspace topologies on $X_1$ and $X_2,$ as subspaces of $X_1\cup X_2,$ co-incide with their topologies induced by $d_1$ and $d_2.$

(2). If $X_1\cap X_2 \ne \emptyset$ this may not be possible. Example: For $j\in \{1,2\}$ let $$X_j=(\mathbb Q\times \{0\})\cup ((\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q)\times \{j\}), $$ and let $d_j((x,u),(y,v))=|x-y|$ for $(x,u),(y,v)\in X_j.$ Note that each $X_j$ is an isometric copy of $\mathbb R.$

Suppose $T$ is a topology on $X_1\cup X_2$ such that the subspace topologies on $X_1$ and $X_2$ are generated by the metrics $d_1,d_2.$

Let $(q_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a  sequence in  $\mathbb Q$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty}|q_n-\sqrt 2|=0.$

Consider any $U_1, U_2\in T$  such that $(\sqrt 2,1)\in U_1$  and $ (\sqrt 2,2)\in U_2.$
For $j\in \{1,2\}$ the set $U_j\cap X_j$ is a nbhd of $(\sqrt 2,j)$ in the space $X_j,$ and  $\lim_{n\to \infty}d_j((\sqrt 2,j)(q_n,0))=\lim_{n\to \infty}|\sqrt 2 -q_n|=0.$

Therefore, for $j\in \{1,2\}$ the set $\{n\in \mathbb N: (q_n,0)\not \in U_j\cap X_j\}$ is finite, so $\{n\in \mathbb N:q_n \not \in U_j\}$ is finite. So $q_n\in U_1\cap U_2$ for all but finitely many $n\in \mathbb N.$

So it is not possible that $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset.$ So the points $(\sqrt 2,1) ,(\sqrt 2,2)$ do not have disjoint nbhds in $X_1\cup X_2.$ So the topology $T$ on $X_1\cup X_2$ is not Haudorff, and cannot be generated by a metric.

Remark: There does exist a non-Hausdorff topology $T$ on $X_1\cup X_2$ such that the subspace topologies on $X_1$ and $X_2$, as subspaces of $X_1\cup X_2,$ are generated by the metrics $d_1,d_2.$

Answer (score 0):

This might be cheating, but you can equip any set $Z$ with the discrete metric

$$d: Z \times Z \to \mathbb{R}^+$$

which is defined by $d(x,y) =0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y) =1$ if $x \neq y$ and the set $Z$  will become a metric space.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are explicitly considering overlapping underlying sets, you have to explicitly specify what you want for the intersection. The problem is that if you have arbitrary metrics, then for $x,y\in X_1\cap X_2$ you may have $d_1(x,y)\ne d_2(x,y)$.

Note that I'm consistently assuming non-empty intersection in this post. If the intersection is empty, the answer by Dimiter Skordev gives a viable metric.

Now one way to proceed is to demand that the metrics are compatible, that is to demand that for points in the intersection the two metrics actually agree. In that case, it is easy to build a common metric:
$$d(x,y) = \begin{cases}
d_1(x,y) & x,y\in X_1\\
d_2(x,y) & x,y\in X_2\\
\inf\limits_{a\in X_1\cap X_2} d_1(x,a)+d_2(a,y) & x\in X_1, y\in X_2\\
\inf\limits_{a\in X_1\cap X_2} d_2(x,a)+d_1(a,y) & x\in X_2, y\in X_1
\end{cases}$$

If the metrics are not compatible in that way, you have to specify what you want to preserve from the new metric. One possibility would be that the new metric should be upper-bounded by each of the given metrics. This can be ensured by the following construction:

Let's define a “hopping path” $H$ from $a$ to $b$ as finite sequence $(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with the following properties:

- $x_0=x$, $x_n=y$.
- $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$ are both in $X_1$ or both in $X_2$.

Now we can define the “hop distance” $h$ between two subsequent points as follows (note that this is not yet the metric!):
$$h(x_k,x_{k+1}) = \begin{cases}
\min\{d_1(x_k,x_{k+1}),d_2(x_k,x_{k+1})\} & x_1,x_2\in X_1\cap X_2\\
d_1(x_k,x_{k+1}) & \text{one of the points is only in $X_1$}\\
d_2(x_k,x_{k+1} & \text{one of the points is only in $X_2$}
\end{cases}$$
We then define the “hopping length” of a hopping path as the sum of its hopping distances:
$$l(H) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} h(x_k,x_{k+1})$$
Now we can define the metric $d(a,b)$ as the infimum of the hopping lengths of all hopping paths from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: This is a cool solution, but I do worry about that “min” in the definition of h. Inside $X_1\cap X__2$ this would mean the metric is essentially the minimum of two metrics, which is not generally a metric. We might need to choose the maximum there.

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA: No, it does *not* mean that the metric is essentially the minimum of the two metrics (otherwise I would have defined them that way, instead of going to the trouble of defining “hopping paths”). For example, consider the case that both sets are $\mathbb R^2$ (so that they overlap everywhere), $d_1$ is the usual Euclidean metric, and $d_2$ is the metric that counts the number of coordinates in which the two  points differ. This is an example where the minimum of both metrics would not give a metric. Now consider the points $a=(0,0)$ and $b=(0.75,1.8)$. …

Comment: … Then we have $d_1(a,b)=1.95$ and $d_2(a,b)=2$, the minimum of which clearly is $1.95$. However consider the "hopping path" $(a,p,b)$ with $p=(0.75,0)$. Then we have $d_1(a,p) = 0.75 < d_2(a,p) = 1$ and $d_2(p,b) = 1 < d_1(p,b) = 1.8$, and therefore the hopping length of this path is $0.75 + 1 = 1.75 < 1.95$. Since the new metric is defined as the infimum of all hopping lengths from a to b, therefore we have $d(a,b) \le 1.75 < \min\{d_1(a,b),d_2(a,b)\}$.

Comment: Oh I see. So the hopping path is designed specially to overcome that issue. Thanks for clarifying.